# JS newbie: how to execute part of the HTML after clicking on a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am fairly new to JS and jQuery and I am stuck with this.

I am doing an ecommerce and I have a page showing the details of a product.
I have a **carousel of thumbnail**. If you click on the thumbnail, the main image gets substituted with the selected one.

Then, in another portion of the page, I have some little **color boxes**: if you select one of them (e.g. Red), the list of thumbnails gets filtered and shows only the Red thumbnails. This is done via a custom script that matches the class value of the color boxes to the class value of the thumbnail images.

What I am struggling with is trying to show the bigger image of the selected color too.
The correct use case would be:

1. User opens product page
2. The big image viewer shows the Big image, e.g. a photo of
   the Red version (corresponding to the first thumbnail in the
   carousel) - this is OK
3. Carousel shows 5 thumbnails, 3 corresponding to the Red version of the product, 2 to the yellow one - this is OK
4. user plays with the carousel: a click on a thumbnail triggers the
   corresponding big image - this is OK
5. User decides to filter by colour and clicks on the Yellow little color box - this is OK
6. Carousel gets filtered and shows only the thumbnail of the yellow version of the product - this is OK
7. At the same time as 5. the big image corresponding to the first thumbnail in the filtered list
   shoud be triggered and should pop up in the big image viewer - this is what I am struggling with.

Here's the **code of the big image viewer + carousel**:

```
<div id="product">
    <!-- BIG IMAGE VIEWER - The first that gets loaded is the first big image corresponding to  the first thumbnail --> 
    <div id="productimg"><a href="full_size_red_01.jpg" class="cloud-zoom" id="zoom1" rel="position: 'inside', showTitle: false"><img src="big-red_01.jpg" alt="" title="M1" /></a></div>
     <!-- END BIG IMAGE VIEWER --> 

    <div id="productdet">
    <!-- THUMBNAILS CAROUSEL -->
      <ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
      <li><a href='full_size_red_01.jpg' class='cloud-zoom-gallery' rel="useZoom: 'zoom1', smallImage: 'big_red_01.jpg' " title='M1'><img src="thumb_red_01.jpg" alt="M1" class="Rosso/Red" /></a></li>
      <li><a href='full_size_red_02.jpg' class='cloud-zoom-gallery' rel="useZoom: 'zoom1', smallImage: 'big_red_02.jpg' " title='M1'><img src="thumb_red_02.jpg" alt="M1" class="Rosso/Red" /></a></li>
      <li><a href='full_size_red_03.jpg' class='cloud-zoom-gallery' rel="useZoom: 'zoom1', smallImage: 'big_red_03.jpg' " title='M1'><img src="thumb_red_03.jpg" alt="M1" class="Rosso/Red" /></a></li>
      <li><a href='full_size_yellow_01.jpg' class='cloud-zoom-gallery' rel="useZoom: 'zoom1', smallImage: 'big_yellow_01.jpg' " title='M1'><img src="thumb_yellow_01.jpg" alt="M1" class="Rosso/Red" /></a></li>
      <li><a href='full_size_yellow_02.jpg' class='cloud-zoom-gallery' rel="useZoom: 'zoom1', smallImage: 'big_yellow_02.jpg' " title='M1'><img src="thumb_yellow_02.jpg" alt="M1" class="Rosso/Red" /></a></li>

      </ul>
    <!-- END THUMBNAILS CAROUSEL -->
    </div>
```

And here's the code of the **color selection tool**:

```
<div class="controls color">
    <label class="Rosso/Red"><input type="radio" name="modifiers[1]" value="1" /> Rosso/Red</label>                             
    <label class="Giallo/Yellow"><input type="radio" name="modifiers[1]" value="2" /> Giallo/Yellow</label>                             
    </div>
</div>
```

The thumbnails+big image viewer logic is managed via jcarousel.

The custom js that manages the thumbnails filtering is this:

```
var select = {
wrapper: null,
controls: null,
resetBtn: $('<p id="reset">Vedi tutti i colori</p>'),
images: null,
carousel: null,
carouselBtns: null,
isClickable: false,
init: function(){
    this.carousel = $('#mycarousel');
    this.wrapper = $('#productdet');
    this.controls = $('div.controls');
    this.images = this.wrapper.find('img');

},
filter: function(){
    this.controls.on('click', 'input[type="radio"]', function(){
        select.carouselBtns = select.wrapper.find('div.jcarousel-clip').nextAll('div');
        var filterName = $(this).closest('label').attr('class').split('/')[0],
            filteredImg = select.wrapper.find('img[class*="'+filterName+'"]'),
            itemLen = select.wrapper.find('li').length;

        if( filteredImg.length ){
            select.controls.find('label').removeClass('on');
            $(this).closest('label').addClass('on');

            select.images.closest('li').hide();

            select.wrapper.find('div.jcarousel-clip').nextAll('div.jcarousel-prev').click();
            filteredImg.closest('li').show(0, function(){
                if ( filteredImg.length < 5 ) {//itemLen

                    select.carouselBtns.hide();

                }
            });
        }

        select.isClickable = true;
        select.preventItemAdding();
    });
},
preventItemAdding: function(){
    var add = $('#add');

    if ( !select.isClickable ) {
        add.addClass('off');
    }else{
        add.removeClass('off');
    }
},

resetAll: function(){
    select.resetBtn.click(function(){
        select.controls.find('label').removeClass('on');
        select.images.closest('li').show();
        select.carousel.jcarousel('reload');

        select.carouselBtns.show();
        select.isClickable = false;
        select.preventItemAdding();
    });
}
};
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you!!

SOLUTION

I added a couple of lines in the JS, in the 'filter' function (thanks to @vrutberg):

```
var imageUrl = $(".jcarousel-item:visible:eq(0) .cloud-zoom-gallery").attr("rel").substr(31).slice(0, -2);
$("#productimg #wrap #zoom1 img").attr("src", imageUrl);
```

Comment: should we imagine what is the script?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I have just updated my question with some more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I think you need to do, if I read your question correctly, is add some code just before the `filter` function exits, that basically does this:

1. Find the first visible image in the image carousel (tip: use the :visible selector http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)
2. Extract the file name from it
3. Set the correct file names on the big image

That should do the trick. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, I managed to sort it out!!! That was exactly the perfect way to do it. And it was quite easy! I edited the post with the solution @vrutberg

Comment: Great! :) Can you also mark my answer correct if you feel it helped you?